# How can I convert ¶ (pilcrow) to \n in PHP after reading a record from MySQL

Tags: php

In the following code when I echo the text in "Details" column after retrieving the record from mySQL database, I want it to echo line break (< br/ >) for all the ¶ (pilcrows) in the database record.

I know I can use `nl2br()` to replace all \n to `<br/>`, but first I need to replace all ¶ (pilcrows) to `\n`. How can I do it? Here is my code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['Details'];
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php): `str_replace('¶', '<br>', $row["Details']);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use something like `$row['Details'] = str_replace("¶", "\n", $row['Details']);`. That will change every pilcrow into a newline (as long as the pilcrow isn't encoded, of course).

Answer (score 3):

Use the PHP function [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
str_replace('¶', '<br>', $row["Details"]);
```